Apple II sales by sector
Of the American 8-bit personal computers, the Apple II was arguably the most general, in that it sold well to home enthusiasts (Woz's original intended target market), schools (thanks in part to the MECC, in part to Jobs and the "Kids can't wait" effort, and in part simply to having color when other computers were monochrome) and business (floppy disk drive, 80-column card, and the historical contingency of being the initial platform for VisiCalc).
I would be interested in just how many (of the estimated lifetime total of about 6 million) were sold to each sector. Equivalent figures for the BBC Micro, the closest UK equivalent, are given in this document which says:

By October 1983, demand from schools had increased, with 25 per cent of the total sales coming from education, 35 per cent from home users, and 40 per cent from business users.

What would be the equivalent figures for the Apple II?

Is there not a similar web page to the pagetable  (but for the Apple II) as per Raffzahn's comment under Commodore 64 software sales peak year?

This answer might be of some help: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/459/over-its-lifetime-how-many-apple-ii-computers-were-sold
